# Find maximum average salary and print it (even if there are multiples), I'm missing decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the maximum average salary per department.  Then I need to return only departments (NAME and DEPT_MAX_AVG_SALARY) that have that maximum average salary with two decimal places (i.e., it might be more than one that have the same max average salary, and that is fine, we need all departments that equal that amount).

```
 SELECT p.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.NAME, cast(AVG(p.SALARY) as decimal(18,2)) as AVERAGE
  FROM PROFESSOR p 
  INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d   ON p.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.ID
  GROUP BY p.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.NAME

  HAVING AVG(p.SALARY) =
  (
  SELECT TOP 1 AVG(a.SALARY) as MAXAVERAGE
  FROM PROFESSOR a 
  INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT b
  ON a.DEPARTMENT_ID = b.ID
  GROUP BY a.DEPARTMENT_ID
  ORDER BY MAXAVERAGE DESC
  )
  ORDER BY AVERAGE DESC
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "maximum average"? Do you want the maximum or do you want the average?

Comment: @KenWhite -- MSSQL ... I added sql-server, was there a better tag that I missed besides this new one of "sql-server"?  I'll take recommendations :)

Comment: @JaimeDrq -- I mean after calculating the average salary per department, then return the greatest value out of all department's average salaries.

Comment: You could also add a tag for the specific version of SQL Server as well as the generic [tag:sql-server]. But the one you added will help. :-) I'll remove my original comment - thanks for the edit.

Comment: I think you are just asking for the maximum from the query you provided. In that case, Select Max([AVERAGE]) as [MaxSalaryForAllDepartments] From (<your query above>) as subquery. The “Order by average desc” should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(d.avg) from (
    select avg(salary) "avg" from professor group by department  
) as d
```

This is obviously a stripped down version but the logic is there. You select the max from the average computed in the derived table, which is grouped by the department.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should try `WITH TIES` and `ORDER BY`:

```
Select TOP 1 WITH TIES
 d.NAME as dep_name
,AVG(cast(p.SALARY as decimal(18,2)) as avg_dep_salary
From PROFESSOR p
Inner join DEPARTMENT d on p.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.ID
Group by
 d.ID
,d.NAME
Order by avg_dep_salary desc
```

Answer (score 0):

`TOP (1) WITH TIES` is the way to go.  But I think the query looks like this:

```
select top (1) with ties d.id, d.NAME as dep_name,
       cast(avg(p.SALARY) as decimal(18, 2)) as avg_dep_salary
from PROFESSOR p Inner join
     DEPARTMENT d 
     on p.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.ID
group by d.ID, d.NAME
order by avg_dep_salary desc;
```

It is important to cast the value *after* calculating the average.  If `salary` is an integer, then you may need:

```
       cast(avg(p.SALARY * 1.0) as decimal(18, 2)) as avg_dep_salary
```

Comment: What's the profit of casting average salary type int to decimal? Adding ".00" at the end? That's useless operation. If you cast before calculating an average, you'll get correct answer. For example: professor A salary is 105, professor B - 100. According to your answer the result will be 102.00, because you cast int 102 to decimal 102.00, according to my answer, the result will be 102.50000, which is considered to be more correct calculation.

Comment: @AlexSham . . . An operation like `average()` changes the number of decimal places.  The rules for precision and scale with decimal numbers are very arcane.  The question is explicitly asking for the average to two decimal places, not the average of salary to two decimal place.  So, I disagree that converting before taking the average is what the question is asking for.

Comment: Yes, I just thought, that OPs salary is of type int. But it may be also decimal with more digits after a dot. So you are right.